# Workflow 2013 stucks in Suspended mode

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow2013

we are having this issue in SP Workflow 2013  when creating a new item. 
I created a simple workflow like setting a value under a specific condition. That workflow goes to started, after while it is changed to Suspended and no action happened !!

This error message that I have got when WF is Started:

> Activity in progress
>
> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to
>   https://myserver.fqdn/sites/teamsite/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'9d2a1222-3879-46b5-9636-0326f905d80e')/Items(27)
>   Correlation Id: Instance Id: c1890e57-5ffc-4f7c-b105-b724bbe2b26b
>   Retry now

and this message when it is Suspended:

> " RequestorId: 58a83ea3-c586-a6f3-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: Input at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>
> "

Comment: Can you pls add screenshot of the workflow steps to investigate further?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEqIJ.png ... as I said it is a simple workflow, I just created it for testing .. and as you see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR9My.png the workflow column is empty, it doesn't display  WF stage.

Comment: you first send an email. I remember that I had the same problem a couple of months ago and the solution was a missing relay in the mail server and that the mail server didn't except sending mails triggered by anonymous SharePoint sender

Comment: I tried running workflow without sending email but still not wirkong, so I don't think it's related to mail server